# How to get nid as int (and not as string)

Tags: 7, database

This code snippet:

```
var_dump(
    db_query("select nid, title from node limit 1")->fetchAssoc()
);
```

Prints this:

```
array(2) {
  ["nid"]=>
  string(4) "6247"
  ["title"]=>
  string(5) "test!"
}
```

The database table `node` though has the following structure:

```
nid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
...
title varchar(255) NOT NULL
...
```

Is there a way to make the query above return `nid` as an int?

Comment: Not directly from the query but you could use normal PHP functionality to acheive the same when it comes to using that variable e,g, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php

Comment: Useful related reading: https://florentpoujol.fr/2018/01/08/how-to-get-integer-columns-actual-integer-php-pdo-mysql/. In summary, unless you're prepared to change how you query the database, just cast to the correct type

Comment: Check also this answer from @Clive on a similar question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/152843/20765